# Apex classes should escape/sanitize Strings obtained from URL parameters: How?

Tags: apex, pmd

I have the following line of code in my visualforce controller.

```
caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseId');
```

I am using PMD, which is a static code analyzer. It complains me of `ApexXSSFromURLParam: Apex classes should escape/sanitize Strings obtained from URL parameters`.

I studied a bit on this and found that `String.escapeSingleQuotes` is a useful way to avoid SOQL injection attacks. So I rewrote it as follows:

```
caseId = String.escapeSingleQuotes(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseId'));
```

But PMD is still complaining me about the same issue.

Is there anything else that I need to do in order to escape/sanitize the string?

Comment: which version of PMD are you on?

Comment: PMD version: 5.8.0

Comment: hmm, I'm using PMD 6.3.0 [w/ruleset 2.0.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmd/pmd/master/pmd-apex/src/main/resources/rulesets/apex/ruleset.xml) and with a sample class with your line of code, I do not get that inspection error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseId').escapeHtml4();
```

I had a similar issue with `String.escapeSingleQuotes()` and this resolved it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"Do not use the built in Apex String Encoding functions: String.escapeEcmaScript(), String.escapeHtml3(), and String.escapeHtml4(). These functions are based on Apache's StringEscapeUtils package which was not designed for security encoding and should not be used."
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_cross_site_scripting.htm

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: It also would be more helpful to make this comment if it is followed by a recommended alternative.

Comment: @Adrian Larson, true but the post is however very useful as the accepted answer leads, according to documentation, to a dangerous practice, and the page from the link provided has complete documentation that would be hard to summarize here given the amount of data it provides.