Resolving ApexXSSFromURLParam scanner issues while preserving reasonable values
I'm doing some proactive code cleanup based on scanner results and trying to find a way to remove ApexXSSFromURLParam issues while maintaining proper functionality.
Consider the code...
String testMe = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('testMe');
String something = testMe; // This line gets a ApexXSSFromURLParam rule violation

Suppose the caller of the page wants to pass value-- It's big & heavy.
They construct URL-- https:..../pageName?testMe=It%27s%20big%20%26%20heavy.
How can the code be made safe without corrupting the value?
Trying all the following, the value is not preserved correctly.
String testMe = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('testMe')?.escapeEcmaScript();
String testMe = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('testMe')?.escapeHtml3();
String testMe = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('testMe')?.escapeHtml4();
String testMe = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('testMe')?.escapeXML();

The first changes it to-- It\'s big & heavy.
The other three change it to-- It&#39;s big &amp; heavy.

see Daniel Ballinger's which gives some context about the intent of the rule and some good mitigation strategies:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233885/apex-classes-should-escape-sanitize-strings-obtained-from-url-parameters-how

As far as ApexPMD goes, the proper way to deal with this rule is as follows:
// NOPMD
String something = testMe; // This line would get a ApexXSSFromURLParam violation

This is a half-baked rule. While it has good intentions, PMD's current scanning capabilities limits this rule from being useful most of the time. The intent of the rule is to make developers aware of a potential issue if they later use this string as a Visualforce output, as part of a Rich Text field in a record, as the body of an HTML email message, etc. If you're not doing potentially vulnerable activities, this is effectively a false positive.
When you run the Checkmarx scanner, if this line still comes up as an XSS vulnerability, then you should be concerned. However, this usually only comes up in the form of Visualforce vulnerabilities, and so can be mitigated in those scenarios with the appropriate Visualforce function or attribute, such as <apex:outputText value="{!testme}" escape="true" /> or {!HTMLENCODE(testme)}.

I concur with your opinion.  I did ask about the SF Source Scanner on the Partner Portal and it was mentioned that everything must be address in the source scanner also.  I'll have to document these as false positives.
In general, i've found many of the rules to be to primitive to be useful.  For example, a hit on every dynamic soql query from a string when I've assembled the string in the line before with only constants and ":" variable references.
